# Swfit: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error occurs

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm making an app that uses Google Maps/Places API and I'm using the GMSAutocomplete View Controller. Once the user chooses a location, I show that location's restaurants on both a map and a table view, but I get the error mentioned above in the title and I'm not sure why.

The error happens at this instruction:

> mapViewController.mapView.camera = camera

```
// OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var mapButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var listButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
@IBOutlet var toggle : [UIButton]!

// VARIABLES

var listViewController = exploreListViewController!
var mapViewController = exploreMapsViewController!

var viewControllers : [UIViewController]!
var selectedIndex : Int = 0

var listVC = exploreListViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    listButton.roundCorners([.topLeft,.bottomLeft], radius: 5, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
    mapButton.roundCorners([.topRight,.bottomRight], radius: 5, borderColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 5)


    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    listViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "list") as! exploreListViewController
    mapViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "maps") as! exploreMapsViewController

    viewControllers = [listViewController, mapViewController]
    toggle[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
    toggleViews(toggle[selectedIndex])

}

@IBAction func toggleViews(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // REMOVING PREVIOUS VIEW CONTROLLER

    let previousIndex = selectedIndex
    let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]

    selectedIndex = sender.tag
    toggle[previousIndex].isSelected = false

    previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

    // ADDING SELECTED VIEW CONTROLLER

    sender.isSelected = true
    let currentVC = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

    addChildViewController(currentVC)
    currentVC.view.frame = container.bounds
    container.addSubview(currentVC.view)
    currentVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

@IBAction func switchToList(_ sender: UIButton) {

    listButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    listButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    listButton.roundCorners([.bottomLeft,.topLeft], radius: 5, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)

    mapButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    mapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    mapButton.roundCorners([.bottomRight,.topRight], radius: 5, borderColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 5)

}

@IBAction func switchToMap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    mapButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    mapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    mapButton.roundCorners([.bottomRight,.topRight], radius: 5, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)

    listButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    listButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    listButton.roundCorners([.bottomLeft,.topLeft], radius: 5, borderColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 5)

}

// MARK: GOOGLE AUTOCOMPLETE DELEGATE


// WHEN USER SUCCESSFULLY CHOOSES LOCATION

public func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace){

    let googleURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(place.coordinate.latitude),\(place.coordinate.longitude)&types=restaurants&radius=50000&key=MY_API_KEY"

    let cityPicture = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(place.coordinate.latitude),\(place.coordinate.longitude)&types=locality&radius=50000&key=MY_API_KEY"

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15)

    // LIST VIEW

    listViewController.cityName.removeAll()
    listViewController.cityURL.removeAll()
    listViewController.placeNames.removeAll()
    listViewController.imageURL.removeAll()

    listViewController.cityLabel.text = String(describing: place.name)
    listViewController.getCityInfo(url: cityPicture)
    listViewController.callAlamo(url: googleURL)

    // MAP VIEW

    mapViewController.mapView.camera = camera // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    mapViewController.callAlamo(url: googleURL)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// WHEN AN ERROR OCCURS

public func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){

    print("ERROR: ",error)
}

// WHEN USER PRESSES CANCEL BUTTON

public func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController){

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func openPlacePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()

    autoCompleteController.delegate = self
    self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>
> a non-optional type with a nil List item value
>
> a failed forced type conversion

So I could imagine that you try to work with data that is nil. Check `mapViewController` if it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tempVC` is assigned to `mapViewController` which is never initialized.

What is the reason for having your `tempXX` vars? It makes your code very confusing.

In any case, change the:

```
var mapViewController : exploreMapsViewController!
```

To:

```
var mapViewController = exploreMapsViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you had suggested, but the problem still persists. I've updated my code above for more convenience. If you have any more suggestions, then please don't hesitate to share.

Comment: In that case your `mapView` is probably not instantiated.

Comment: So you were right about mapView not being instantiated properly, and I found out that when you open the app for the first time and open up the Autocomplete view controller from the listViewController,  but don't go to the mapViewController, the app will crash because it hasn't even seen the mapViewController. So now my question is, how would you suggest I go about doing that. I apologize if this seems like a pretty basic question. I'm still a bit new to Swift and all of it's nuances.

Comment: Don't try to access UI elements that are not on screen. Update variables like users position instead. Then when view appears you implement `viewWillAppear` in respective view controller and update your elements based on what data you have at that moment.

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution to my problem. I was informed about a new function that was created loadViewIfNeeded(), and it works perfectly.